# What is the meaning of 「はあ」 in this excerpt?

Tags: meaning, archaic-language, literature

## 日本語

こんにちは。

川上弘美著の「神様」という小説を読んでいます。
「河童玉」という章の以下のくだりに、男河童と女河童と人間のウテナさんの三人がいます。

> 「ほれご挨拶を」と（*男河童に*）うながされて、女河童はもじもじしながら頭を下げた。下げるなり、ウテナさんににじり寄って、「うちのひとが**はあ**お世話に。河童玉やらなにやら、できることは全部してみたんですが、いまひとつ効果なしなんですよう、せつないやらつまらんやら**はあ**」と喋りはじめた。

現在の日本語と違った言葉なのかなと思いますが、上の「はあ」はどういう意味でしょうか？

悲しさやら感慨深さを強調して表す助詞だと思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

## English

> 「ほれご挨拶を」と（*男河童に*）うながされて、女河童はもじもじしながら頭を下げた。下げるなり、ウテナさんににじり寄って、「うちのひとが**はあ**お世話に。河童玉やらなにやら、できることは全部してみたんですが、いまひとつ効果なしなんですよう、せつないやらつまらんやら**はあ**」と喋りはじめた。

What is the meaning of `はあ` in the excerpt cited above?
From the context I would guess it is an interjection that is supposed to emphasize emotions, maybe in particular ones like sadness.

Comment: This site uses English as the primary mode of communication when asking questions. I suggest posting your question in English, with the relevant context in Japanese.

Comment: kandyman - repeated the question in English at the end and changed the title. I hope that is better now.

Comment: @kandyman Frustrating as it can be for those of us whose Japanese sucks (me at least), I believe the community agreed many years ago that questions and answers solely in Japanese were acceptable.

Comment: @user3856370 Sure, that's why I suggested it rather than telling outright it wasn't acceptable.

Comment: `This site uses English as the primary mode of communication` It's interesting Japanese comments and answers slightly increased after this comment posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

読点がないのが不親切ですが、感動詞（間投詞）の「はあ」だと思います。この文脈だと以下のいずれかの意味だと思います。

- 肯定も否定もできない時、やや疑問に感じている時、不審に思いながらもとりあえず話を続ける時、あまり乗り気でない時などに使われる「はあ」。[こちら](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82/#jn-172841)の2番目の定義です。この場合、女河童はウテナのことをあまり歓迎しておらず不審に思っているが、とりあえず言われて挨拶をしている、ということになります。英語だと、"well...", "um...", "oh, is that so..." あたりに対応すると思います。こちらは現代語でもよく使われます。
- 相手に対してへりくだる「はあ」。時代劇などで農民が領主に「はい」と言う代わりに「はあ」「はっ」「ははあー」と言うのを聞いたことがないでしょうか。その「はあ」です。英語だと "(yes) sir" とか "aye" が近いと思います。現代語では滅多に使われません。

1990年代に書かれた普通の現代小説のようですし、女河童は特に堅苦しいしゃべり方ではなさそうなので、前者の可能性が高いとは思います。この女河童の態度や、他の場面でどのようなしゃべり方をしているかと比べてください。単なるこの女河童の口癖という可能性もあると思います。

Answer (score 1):

もう少し文脈やあらすじなどどういった話かが分からないとあまりよく分からないのですが、おそらくこの「はあ」は主に当惑を表しているのではないでしょうか？ため息をついているのでしょうか。なので、助詞ではなく[間投詞](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%84%9F%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E)だと思います。

古来からあるかも知れませんが、特に古風な表現ではないと思います。友達に「また遊ぼうぜ。」って連絡しても、「はあ、頼みますわ。」って返信が来たりしますし。ただこの場合は単なる同調の「はい」なのか最近忙しいから「はあ」とため息をついているのかは分かりませんが。

この「はあ」も似た様な類だと思います。特に、「うちのひとが**はあ**お世話に。」とかそう言う感じがします。